# Storing large JSON pipe-lining requests later

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I need to retrieve a big amount of data in my view (in JS) from a server.

The json is about **30 000 000** char length.  this is kinda looks like this (just an example) :

```
[{x:1000,y:1000,t:1505250440},{x:999,y:1000,t:1505250441},{x:998,y:1000,t:1505250442}......]
```

The JSON is updated every hour by pulling data from a table in my database with a CRON.

**Should I store the whole JSON:**

1. In the database (as a row - LONG_TEXT) that would request via SQL and serve with PHP to my view
2. directly in a file that I would request directly from the view in JS
3. Or could I text compress the JSON in any other way?

What's the most efficient way? It is not necessarily needed that I store it in JSON, I could store it more simply with a basic compression like:

```
1000.1000.1505250440-999.999.1505250441-....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the result of the query and just get the whole dataset from the script, saving it in the file seems to be more efficient from the performance standpoint.

And, as you mentioned, store it in JSON is redundant. CSV format doesn't force you to store metadata for each row like JSON keys, so requires less space.

Also, you can compress the results, but decompressin to access data may be less efficient. It depends on how often you need to perform data access and how fast it should be

Comment: You can alway store it as JSON-encoded CSV where each row is actually a JSON array, but the structure is identical. This can side-step wonky CSV parsing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. It really depends on where the bottleneck is and we don't know what else you are doing with this (these) data. I assume you're using cron to gather this data since it would take too long to generate it on the server when the client requested it. I would say A and B are incredibly similar, they take about the same amount of storage on disk and B is only marginally faster.

You're example for C isn't going to buy you much. If you know that these will be  say 32-bit integers then storing them as such will definitely beat storing them as strings. For 64-bits it would depend on the average length of the string Either way gzip could be your friend.

You may also want to think about caching instead of storing if you don't need this long term.

Comment: Well my biggest issue is loading time. I'm gonna try REDIS as a caching system but the question remain : should i stock the whole json in one key of the cache ?

Comment: If you plan to cache the entire JSON string, I would look at apache/nginx caching, additionally think about cache headers on the response. If the data is static, why go all the way back to the database? I would also look at priming the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 3rd option would be the best (if you're wanting smallest byte size) and mix it with the 1st option to store that in a database row.

Personally, if the data is going to be used at a later date for a database query, that's called `pipelining` (storing big data in a temporary location till it's a time where there are many resources available).

To make a basic pipeline, take the data and store it in a text file with something like `data.pipe.txt`, push all your data to it in either raw text, or convert that JSON into [CSV](http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format) to make it smaller.

If you're using PHP mainly to manage and manipulate data, use a more PHP-friendly format, JSON is supported but it's mainly for JavaScript more than anything whereas CSV is nice for PHP to manage, looping each line, you get what I mean.

But since you said the data is pulled from a CRON job, you're best off doing the big manipulation each 24-hours (if that's doable) and storing the data temporarily in a pipeline each hour.

This question was a bit wide-minded, and I felt like talking about pipelines.

Comment: i'm running a cron every hour to dump the data from my DB into the JSON and storing it somewhere. I'm gonna try your point of view, thanks :)

Comment: Aw, I'm taken back @owow, that gives me butterflies inside :)